# Adding J query and bootstrap in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am adding template in MVC4 basic application and the problem is the when I converted my template into MVC4 my slide show ,slider and some other things stopped working.

**BundleConfig.cs:**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryUI").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*","~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include("~/Content/css/bootstrap.css"));
```

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    </head>
    <body>
       @RenderBody()
           @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
           @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
           @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

kindly help i am new to MVC
folder structure for j query and js files are as follow

content->css->

```
          bootstrap.min.css
          templatemo_style.css
          camera.css
```

scripts->js->

```
          bootstrap.min.js
          jquery-ui.min.js
          jquery.min.js
          jquery.singlenav.min.js
          unslider.min.js
```

kindly help and guide me for further studing

Comment: I don't know much about mvc but I don't think you've made slider bundles and i cant see you calling them in your page. maybe this will help :  `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/unslider").Include(
                "~/Scripts/js/unslider.min.js"));` and add this to your page `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unslider")` . Also, im not sure if this will automatically fix priorities but you gotta have jquery first then jquery ui and then bootstrap and then the rest of your libraries

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you add all the required .js files to the `BundleCollection` here's an example of how I added `slider.js` and another file called `common.js`to the bundles in one of my projects:

   ```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/serverManagerBundle").Include(
           "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
           "slider.js",
           "~/Scripts/Common/common.js"));
   ```
2. In _Layout.cshtml render your bundles in the `<head>` section only.If you're using a slider library chances are it needs jQuery to work so in your bundle **make sure jQuery is added before the slider.js**
3. Remember that you need to register your bundles in the `Application_Start` event of the Global.asax file:

   ```
   public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
           FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
           RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
           BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
       }
   }
   ```